# Alineación vertical galerry de producto Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, imagen, woocommerce, elementor, gallery

Estoy probando una galería vertical en cada uno de mis productos. Algo similar a esto: [Ver ejemplo](https://terre-et-metal.fr/product/479/banc-ecole)

He utlizado el siguiente código para que la galería de producto por defecto de woocommerce
pase de horizontal a vertical:

```
.woocommerce-product-gallery {
    display: flex;}
.woocommerce-product-gallery .flex-control-thumbs {
    order: -10;}
.woocommerce div.product div.images .flex-control-thumbs li {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 5px;}
```

Pero las imagenes en miniatura han quedado demasiado pequeñas.
¿Cómo puedo ajustar con un poco de CSS para que se vea similar al ejemplo? Por otra parte, cómo puedo ver la imagen principal completa, sin que me recorte un 20%.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas Gracias

Comment: He actualizado el código, pero la imagen principal aun continua grande:

Comment: Buenas. Sin ver el código HTML que maqueta todo es difícil darse cuenta, pero viendo que tienes la galería al 100% del ancho, el problema viene por el ancho de la columna de la imagen principal. Si le pones un max-width a la imagen principal, la galería de la derecha debería de acompañar en la diferencia de ancho. Ya me dices.